# Getting duplicate rows from Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm using spring data REST with PagingAndSortingRepository to serve a table, when i download it using pagination, i find the same row present in two different pages, the problem occurs for several rows.

Downloaded data should be inserted in a database with unique constraint, so rows must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

i've added the sort parameter for id column then the duplicates disappears.